# How to split up data from a column in a csv file into two separate output csv files?

Tags: python, csv

I have a .csv file, e.g.:

```
ID NAME CATEGORIES
1, x,   AB
2, xx,  AA
3, xxx, BA
```

How would I get this to form two output .csv files based on the category e.g.:

File 1:

```
ID NAME CATEGORY
1, x,   A
2, xx,  A
3, xxx, B
```

File 2:

```
ID NAME CATEGORY
1, x,   B
2, xx,  A
3, xxx, A
```

I have the input and output set up, but just an empty for loop where I'm stumped:

```
records = [line for line in csv.reader(open('test_input.csv', 'rt'), delimiter=',')]
outfile = open('test_output1.csv', 'wt')
outfileWriter = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',')

for record in records:
    #something!
    outfileWriter.writerow(record)

outfile.close()
```

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Do the CATEGORIES field always have value of length 2 (two letters)?

Comment: @user1844098 Try my code it should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv

records = [line for line in csv.reader(open('test_input.csv', 'rt'), delimiter=',')]
outfile1 = open('test_output1.csv', 'wt')
outfile2 = open('test_output2.csv', 'wt')
outfileWriter1 = csv.writer(outfile1, delimiter=',')
outfileWriter2 = csv.writer(outfile2, delimiter=',')

# headers always the same
outfileWriter1.writerow(records[0])
outfileWriter2.writerow(records[0])

for record in records[1:]:
    cat = record[-1].strip() # get category in form "AB"
    new_record = record
    new_record[-1] = "\t%s" % cat[0] # set category for file 1 with tab as a prefix
    outfileWriter1.writerow(new_record)
    new_record[-1] = "\t%s" % cat[1] # set category for file 2 with tab as a prefix
    outfileWriter2.writerow(new_record)

outfile1.close()
outfile2.close()
```

Comment: This is just returning the first and second characters from the ID (first) column?

Comment: No, it produces the output that you want: record[-1] returns the last column

Comment: No I mean I ran it, and test_output1.csv is just returning the first digit from the ID column and no other data, and test_output2.csv is returning the second digit from the ID column and no other data.

Comment: I used your input file and it produces the wanted output. Try again and make sure to paste the whole code.

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I am working with a .csv file similar but not exactly the same as the one I described. You're right, it does work with the one I described. I'll do a bit of tweaking to get it to work with the .csv file I'm working with.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
with open('input.csv') as f, open('file1.csv', 'w') as f1, open('file2.csv', 'w') as f2:
    header = next(f)    #read header
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', skipinitialspace=True) 
    f1.write(header)    #write header
    f2.write(header)    #write header
    writ1 = csv.writer(f1, delimiter=',') 
    writ2 = csv.writer(f2, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        c1, c2 = row[-1]          #split the category into c1 and c2
        writ1.writerow(row[:-1] + [c1])  #write c1 to file1
        writ2.writerow(row[:-1] + [c2])  #write c2 to file2
```