# How to divide some csv files into two parts, and then merge them as an csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, merge

I already read [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427763/how-to-split-up-data-from-a-column-in-a-csv-file-into-two-separate-output-csv-fi), but it is different, and this is based on columns.

There are 40 csv files; file1.csv, file2.csv. ..., file40.csv in a folder called pathImage. they have been merged accurately by the following code, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31620829/how-to-read-some-csv-files-in-a-folder-in-python):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv('file%d.csv' % x) for x in range(1,41)])
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

What I want know is that how can we split them into two parts, and then merge the as the above code into two csv files, part1 an part2?

**Update:** 
I want two csv files, for example train.csv and test.csv files. Train file is %80 of the original csv file, and the rest would be test csv file.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use np.array_split, use np.split()

```
# Perfunctory imports.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Confirm the length of your initial dataframe.
len(df)

# Create two new data frames, via split, split it multiplying the 
# length of the original dataframe by .80 (80%).
# np.split returns a list of arrays, so we can use the tuple 
# syntax to simply assign to two separate data frames in one go.
# The larger of the two based on the split will be the first df.
train_df, test_df  = np.split(lahman_data, [int(len(df) * .80)])

# Output the two dataframes to separate files
train_df.to_csv('train.csv')
test_df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

If you use iPython, you should be able to confirm what is going on via:

```
help(np.split())
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The numpy function array_split should do the trick:

```
import numpy as np
np.array_split(df,2)
```

It will return an array of 2 pandas objects.

Comment: I want two csv files, for example train.csv and test.csv files. Train file is %80 of the original csv file, and the rest would be test csv file.